# Swift 3 - Set X-Y axis UILabel per device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, cgrect

I've label and I given values of X-Y axis, but my values didn't put label on the center per device, and I wrote method of width size if device is big set width size 50 else smaller but this method not working in iPhone SE, 5S/5, 6/6s/7 just working with iPhone 6+/6S+/7+!! For example like this

[image]

So what's wrong and what additions should I add ??

```
let lengthOfChar : CGFloat = data.ans.length // Characters form SQLite database
let yAxis : CGFloat = self.view.frame.height / 3 * 1.8
let width: CGFloat = view.frame.size.width - 40 // frame width
var targetWidth: CGFloat = (width - (lengthOfChar - 1) * 5) / lengthOfChar

if targetWidth > 50 {
    targetWidth = 50
}

let totalWidth: CGFloat = (targetWidth * lengthOfChar) + ((lengthOfChar - 5) * 5)
let x : CGFloat = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2)
let xx : CGFloat = (CGFloat(indexTar) * targetWidth) + (CGFloat(indexTar) * 5) + 20
var xAxis : CGFloat = (x + xx)
xAxis = width - xAxis
```

Comment: Use auto.layout and constraints it is much easier and very powerful

Comment: it might be easier for you to use autolayout

Comment: I can't because my project created by code and I can't return the project @Phyber

Comment: I will show you how to use auto layout in code

Comment: where should be the label ?

Comment: Between a square label (purple) and 14 buttons @Phyber

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a helper enum that allows doing custom things for certain iPhones. Sett the **enum** and **usage** below.

Add a **new class** with this code:

```
enum DeviceType: Int {
  case iPhone4 = 1
  case iPhone5
  case iPhone6
  case iPhone6Plus
  case iPad

  init(userInterfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom, screenHeight: CGFloat) {
    switch (userInterfaceIdiom, screenHeight) {
    case (.phone, 0..<568.0):
        self = .iPhone4
    case (.phone, 568.0..<667.0):
        self = .iPhone5
    case (.phone, 667.0..<736.0):
        self = .iPhone6
    case (.phone, 736.0..<CGFloat.infinity):
        self = .iPhone6Plus
    case (.pad, _):
        self = .iPad
    default:
        self = .iPhone6
    }
  }

  func isSameOrSmaller(than deviceType: DeviceType) -> Bool {
    return self.rawValue <= deviceType.rawValue
  }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
if UIDevice.current.type().isSameOrSmaller(than: .iPhone5) {
    // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: Using auto-layout is so much easier.

Comment: @Phyber seems he needs to do some custom stuff

Comment: How to called this code in ViewController in my function ? @TungFam

Comment: @AmeenMK as I wrote in the answer: `UIDevice.current.type().isSameOrSmaller(than: .iPhone5)`. let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: show me the error please @AmeenMK. PS: it works perfectly for me.

Comment: UIDevice has no member 'type' @TungFam

Comment: can you please take a screenshot of your code consisting the error? add it to the question. when you've added it ping me in comment so i see it. thanks @AmeenMK

Comment: Do you have tutorial for this form constraint ?? And what's its name ?? Constraint or other name ?? @TungFam

Comment: what swift version are you using? try not to just copy paste the code i wrote but write it yourself. xcode will provide code suggestions. @AmeenMK

Comment: I wrote in subject question swift 3 @TungFam

Answer (score 0):

Using auto-layout in code

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.purpleBox.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

You can do whatever you want with it. This is very powerful.

Some other anchors you can use

```
// centerYAnchor
// leftAnchor
// rightAnchor
// bottomAnchor
```

For further reading: [Working with Layout anchors](https://cocoacasts.com/working-with-auto-layout-and-layout-anchors/)